# Symfony2 error when trying to create entity field in form

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

```
$tip->setGame($em->getRepository('XXXBundle:Game')->find($id));
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($tip)->add('player', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'XXXBundle::FootballPlayer',
        /*'query_builder' => function(\XXX\XXXBundle\Entity\FootballPlayerRepository $er)
        {
          $er->findByCurteam($team->getName());
        },*/
    ))->getForm();
```

(not really using 'XXX' in my code)
error:

> Warning: class_parents(): Class XXX\XXXBundle\Entity\ does not exist
>   and could not be loaded in
>   D:\www\xxx\xxx\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php
>   line 223

seems the Entity class is not found - strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is strange in your code: `'class' => 'XXXBundle::FootballPlayer',` are you sure `::` exist? Never seen it, seems like a mistake (maybe can provoke the error).

After testing, yes, it's because of the double `::` replace by `:`: `'class' => 'XXXBundle:FootballPlayer',`.